# PostgreSQL - Unsure about how to create table with an atribute that stores values with only 2 decimal places

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a table with an amount attribute field but am unsure about how to make it have 2 decimals places only. Could someone show me an example.

Code I have :

```
create table name( FirstName CHAR(15), Amount ????)
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: You also do ***not*** want `char(15)` you want `varchar(15)`

Comment: For Decimal(10,2). Does this mean it can be variable up to 10 digits and will always have 2 decimal places?

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name rightly pointed out... reading the documentation might help. The Documentation clearly says ... [_So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4_]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numeric data type

```
NUMERIC(precision, scale)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html